# how do i display a field that i have got from the address bar?

Tags: php

how do I display a field when I have used a GET command to get it from the address bar from the previous page and then display it in my table?

I have tried to display the field already in the table but no luck. the field is call "Reference"

using the below I want to get the reference into the table. (I have tried the following **echo "" . $row['$Reference'] . "";**)

http://test.com/searchresults.php?Reference=456789
$Reference=$_GET['Reference'];

**search results page**

```
<?php

require_once('auth.php');

$host=""; // Host name 
$username=""; // Mysql username
$password=""; // Mysql password 
$db_name=""; // Database name 
$tbl_name="Physio"; // Table name 

 // Connect to server and select database.
   mysql_connect($host, $username, $password)or die("cannot connect"); 
   mysql_select_db($db_name)or die("cannot select DB");

   // get value of Reference that sent from address bar
 $Reference=$_GET['Reference'];

  $sql="SELECT * FROM $tbl_name WHERE Reference='$Reference'";
 $result=mysql_query($sql);

 $rows=mysql_fetch_array($result);

    if(!isset($_POST['postcode'])) {
  header ("location:index.php");
 } 
     echo "<p> Results </p>" ;
 $search_sql = "SELECT * FROM `Physio` WHERE Postcode like '%" . $_POST['postcode'] . "%'";
$search_query = mysql_query($search_sql);

while ($search_rs = mysql_fetch_array($search_query))
{
echo"<table><tr>" ;
     echo '<th>Reference</th><th>Select</th><th>PhysioReference</th><th>Physio</th><th>Postcode</th><th>Line1</th><th>Tel</th>';
while ($search_rs = mysql_fetch_array($search_query))
     {
     echo '<tr>';
     echo "<td>" . $row['$Reference'] . "</td>";
     echo "<td><a href=\"Physiotoinstruction.php?Reference={$search_rs['Reference']}\">Select</a></td>";
     echo "<td>".$search_rs['PhysioReference'] . "</td>";
     echo "<td>".$search_rs['Name'] . "</td>";
     echo "<td>".$search_rs['Postcode'] . "</td>";
     echo "<td>".$search_rs['Line1'] . "</td>";
     echo "<td>".$search_rs['Tel'] . "</td>";
     echo '</tr>';
     }
  echo '</table>';
}
if (!empty($search_rs))
{
echo "<p> Results Found </p>" ;
}
else
{
    echo "<p> No Results Found </p>" ;
}

   ?>
```

Comment: Please have a look at http://bobby-tables.com/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Variables will not expand when in single quotation marks, and also you're trying to access variable called `$row` which isn't in scope (i.e. doesn't exist at this point). The following should suffice:

```
$rows[$Reference]
```

Or change `$rows` to `$row` earlier in your code, whichever makes most sense semantically.

Comment: same as other answer, i have tried these and they seem correct but still no data is showing, have i used the GET command correctly to enable the display the reference?

Comment: $row hasn't been initialized to anything at that point. $rows has, but there's no variable called $row before you try to access it. I'll update my answer to include this.

Comment: You appear to be using $rows instead of $row. So either change $rows to $row or vice versa (considering you only appear to be fetching one result, $row would probably make the most sense)

Comment: I might have used the wrong code here looking at it,i think i need to remove the rows. - how do i display the reference, from the $_GET['Reference']; and display it in the column of the table. many thanks in advance

Comment: `echo "<td>" . $_GET['Reference'] . "</td>";` or `echo "<td>" . $Reference . "</td>";` if you keep the assigned variable.

Comment: quick question, how would I put 2 variables values into url. the following plus the reference I just put into this table "reference" --- echo "<td><a href=\"Physiotoinstruction.php?PhysioReference={$search_rs['PhysioReference']}\">Select</a></td>";

Comment: GET parameters are delimited by the `&` character (and remember that `&` is a special character in HTML, so will need to be encoded as `&amp;`) - `echo "<td><a href=\"Physiotoinstruction.php?PhysioReference={$search_rs['PhysioReference']}&amp;Reference={$Reference}\"‌​>Select</a></td>";`. If you have any further questions, you might want to consider opening a new question as we're going well beyond the scope of the original question here.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of `$row['$Reference']` use `$row[$Reference]`.

Apart from that **DO NOT USE mysql_* SINCE IT IS DEPRECATED**. Use *mysqli* or *PDO*.

Also, escape parameters which you receive from the web. Otherwise you are vulnerable to mysql injection attacks.

Comment: +1 for the SQL injection warning. Still way too much bad PHP tutorials out there..

Comment: i have tried these and they seem correct but still no data is showing, have i used the GET command correctly to enable the display the reference?

Comment: You should show your table structure and example of data in it if you need more help.

Answer (score 0):

You can use following methods

```
$row["$Reference"] // with double quotes
```

or

```
$row[$Reference]  //no quotes
```

As with single quotes it is considered as string.

Read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3446216/what-is-the-difference-between-single-quoted-and-double-quoted-strings-in-php) for reference.